# How to mock inheritance in a swift struct

Tags: swift, struct

I'm designing the model of my app and wish to have two structs "inherit" in some way. Suppose, the two structs are

```swift
struct Book {
    
    var author: String
    var publisher: String
    
    var isHardcover: Bool
}
```

and

```swift
struct Comic {
    
    var author: String
    var publisher: String
    
    var superhero: String
}
```

and I'm not sure how to design this in an optimal way. I want to

- have the struct be mutable (from a design standpoint meaning that I might want to change the type of the field or add/remove another field later on) and both structs should reflect that change if it affects both
- Be able to put the two structs into one collection

Additionally, the number of structs that implement the common fields is limited and known, so an enum is an option as well.

There are several solutions that I have come up with, but none seem to completely satisfying.

1. Exchange the struct for a class and use inheritance; this does work, but according to apple's guidelines, my use-case fits the one of a struct perfectly
2. Create a "Common" struct and have this common struct be a member of the two structs, i.e.

```swift
struct Common {
    var author: String
    var publisher: String
}
```

```swift
struct Book {
    var common: Common

    var isHardcover: Bool
}
struct Comic {
    var common: Common

    var superhero: String
}
```

The disadvantage is that I always have to call `comic.common.author` which is less readable and less informative but seems the best solution so far

3. Use protocol-inheritance where I define that the implementing struct must conform to the variables; the disadvantage here is that it's not really mutable
4. Use an enum with stored properties

```swift
enum Readable {
    case book(_ book: Book)
    case comic(_ comic: Comic)
}
```

which is also somewhat ugly and does not allow me to simply call `readable.author` (unless I implement that function in the enum but this does not really seem that good since I need verbose switch-statements for every small variable)

The question I'm asking is which of the above if any, should I choose? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You should just use a class.

Answer (score 0):

> Use protocol-inheritance where I define that the implementing struct must conform to the variables; the disadvantage here is that it's not really mutable

I would go for this solution. I'm not sure why you said protocols are not really mutable tho.

You can define a protocol `Book`

```swift
protocol Book {
    var author: String { get set }
    var publisher: String { get set }
}
```

Then use it for all your books "subtypes"

```swift
struct Novel: Book {
    var author: String
    var publisher: String
    
    var isHardcover: Bool
}

struct Comic: Book {
    var author: String
    var publisher: String
    
    var superhero: String
}
```

At this point you can put Avery book into a collection

```swift
let someComic = Comic(author: "author", publisher: "publisher", superhero: "superhero")
var someNovel = Novel(author: "author", publisher: "publisher", isHardcover: true)

let books: [Book] = [someComic, someNovel] // this works fine
```

And mutate a single instance (*note that as struct are value types, this won't update the value inside the array. If you want to, you will need to replace with the updated value manually or use classes.*)

```swift
var books: [Book] = // ...

var updatedBook: Book = books.first!
updatedBook.publisher = "another publisher"

// Update the collection with the updated book.
books[0] = updatedBook
```